# Elements not found after switching to iframe context in TestCafe

Tags: testing, iframe, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

## Original question:

using

```js
browser.switchToFrame(iframeEl);
```

I can switch to a particular iframe window, and that's alright - clicking elements and etc works.

But, for whatever reason, using `Selector` when the `iframe` is the current context, does not work. I suspect that it's because `switchToFrame` is a method on the browser instance, and I'm using `Selector` function imported in such manner:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
```

My question is - if I want to select a particular element within the iframe using testcafe (to read its HTML attributes for example) - how should I approach it? Am I missing something?

### More details from GitHub thread:

More details: I'm creating an iframe with remote `src`, and to that iframe, I later inject some HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I'm 100% sure that the `iframe` will have the DOM element that'd match my requested selector - but still, I get an error: `Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.`

My code looks roughly like this:

```
const iframeEl = await Selector('a-iframe_inner[name="something"]');
    if (await iframeEl.count === 0) {
      await this.fBrowser.switchToMainWindow();
    } else {
      await this.fBrowser.switchToIframe(iframeEl);
    }

const something = await Selector('.something');
```

And on a line with `await Selector` the code breaks. In my other tests, where I'm also accessing the iframe and click some element using `await browser.click(someOtherThing);` it works flawlessly.
I can also read the console state of the iframe without hassle.

I suspect that the content of the `iframe` element might not be ready yet, but I'm wondering how can I wait until it's ready? I've tried setting a `timeout` option to the `Selector` call, but it didn't change anything. Can you share any tips on how to delay getting a selector after switching to iframe context?

## Solution:

Turned out that it was indeed a bug on my part. Sorry. For future gens: Iframe switching and using selectors should work all fine, at least in TestCafe `v0.20.1`. Just make sure that your selectors match and you are really in iframe context, not just think that you are there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to do anything special to make `Selectors` work in iframes. It should work as expected. If they do not wish to create a bug report in the official repository using this [form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md), I would appreciate it if you provide an example that demonstrates the issue.
As for your question, I was not able to reproduce this problem in a simple example. 
Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click me</h1>

<iframe id="frame" src="http://example.com" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Test code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Selector in iframe`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;

const selector = Selector('h1');

test('test', async t => {
    await t.click(selector);

    console.log(await selector.innerText);

    await t.switchToIframe('#frame');

    await t.click(selector);

    console.log(await selector.innerText);
});
```

All clicks work as expected and I was able to get `innerText` of the `Selector` successfully.
In addition, I would recommend you check what element really exists on a page, that `Selector` refers to the existing element and that the element has width and height greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While you have been responding, I have created an issue with more explicit description of my case in TestCafe repository. I'll update the question accordingly. Meanwhile, long story short - is there any way to somehow delay the Selctor to make sure that it will be available? `timeout` option of the selector did not work in my case, I wonder both why and if there are any other options to wait until it appears. I'm 100% sure, that it's present in the iframe *at some point*

Link to the issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3478

Comment: The `timeout` option or the `--selector-timeout` command line option should also work. Let's continue the discussion in the github thread.

Comment: Turned out that it was indeed a bug on my part. Sorry. For future gens: Iframe switching and using selectors should work all fine, at least in TestCafe `v0.20.1`